# d3 line transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**A line chart displays a value over a given period of time (e.g. the last 2 days), one value per day. Users can change this time horizon (to e.g. the last four days).**

Problem: the line transitions are really ugly. I figure the problem is the change in data:

```
state 1:      =>   state 2:
days     value     days      value
--------------     ---------------
today-2    5       today-4     3
today-1    8       today-3     9
                   today-2     5
                   today-1     8
```

In above case, for example, the former first data point with a value of 5 now transitions to the value of 3 and is shifted left to today-4 on the x-axis. What I *would* like to have is that 5 and 8 shifted to the right and remained at their values of 5 and 8, while the two new data points enter the stage from 0. Hope you can imagine what I mean.. if not have a look at this image that shows the current state of tragedy ( transition from 1 week => 4 weeks ):

[image: ugly transition]

Now, I know that when attaching the new data, a key can be assigned ( e.g. in this example, the key would be the date of the value) and I've got that working for circles (that are hidden in this chart and only visible when you mouse-over a value). These circles transition perfectly. Unfortunatly, I could not get this working for the lines here because of the way I structured my charts, I guess:

- each chart is built by an "init_chartX" function that initializes an
  "empty" chart (e.g. append a path for line)
- each chart is updated by an "update_chartX" function.

So in the init function, I set up the line:

```
// Add paths for line1 and line2
svg.append("g")
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line1");
```

And when I try to add the data with key in the update function..

```
svg.selectAll(".line1").data(data, function (d) { return formatDate(d.date); })
```

..the result is an exception because "d" is not defined. I *assume* this is because of the setup of a ".line1" element in the init function, it works just fine when used on circles that are not setup in the init function:

```
var dots1 = svg.selectAll(".circle1").data(data, function (d) { return formatDate(d.date); });

dots1.enter().insert("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle1");
```

The circles are not setup in the initfunction, they are just added on the fly. For the line on the other hand, I could not figure out how to get this done.

**The answer to my question could be a link or some usefull tip**..I've seen the Path Transition pages of Mike Bostock already, also the general update pattern tutorials.. maybe I've been blind there. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This question will earn me a golden tumbleweed badge..

Answer (score 0):

Wow, finally found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034771/d3-js-is-it-possible-to-line-transition-by-key-instead-of-index). Alright, no key-binding lines. That will make smooth transitions for changing data with different length a bit harder but I'm glad I finally know why I kept getting an error ..

**EDIT** 
I found a solution: reverse the data before attaching it to the lines. So my example from above becomes:

```
state 1:      =>   state 2:
days     value     days      value
--------------     ---------------
today-1    8       today-1     8
today-2    5       today-2     5
                   today-3     9
                   today-4     3
```

and the transition works as supposed.. So easy, stupid me I didnt figure that out earlier. (the x-axis is not effected by that, it is still growing in time to the right)