# Keys and transitions in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I'm trying to draw a line graph in D3, with a transition based on a click. I can do it the long way round, describing each line as it goes, but I wanted to simplify the code using a key. I got the idea from [D3 tips and tricks](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/d3js-multi-line-graph-with-automatic.html)

Drawing the lines is fine, but transitioning to the second set of data is proving difficult - all the lines just converge to one. That line would be where the fifth line ought to be.

Here's the relevant bit of code - first defining the scales and he two sets of lines

```
/ Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);


// Define the lines
var line1 = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.data1); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.data2); });
```

Then getting the data, and nesting it, then setting up the key, based on the "symbol" column in the data (the data is all here, it's a bit boring to type out http://www.graphitti.org/admin2/files/experiments/lines_exp_data.tsv)

```
// Get the data
d3.tsv("lines_exp_data.tsv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.year = +d.year;
    d.data1 = +d.data1;
    d.data2 = +d.data2;
    d.data3 = +d.data3;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
y.domain([80, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.data1, d.data2; })]); 


// Nest the entries by symbol
var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.symbol;})
    .entries(data);

// Loop through each symbol / key
dataNest.forEach(function(d) {

    graph.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("id", "lines")
        .attr("d", line1(d.values)); 

});
```

This all works fine. Then I want to change them based on the click, so I do this

```
d3.select("#clickone")
            .on("click", function() {

                 dataNest.forEach(function(d) {

    graph.selectAll("#lines")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
        .attr("d", line2(d.values)); 


;})
;})
```

And what happens then is that all the lines collapse to one line. You can see it all here http://www.graphitti.org/admin2/files/experiments/lines_exp_03.html

Is there a way of doing this? I've seen other questions on SO that suggest it can't be done (e.g. [d3.js: Is it possible to line transition by key instead of index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034771/d3-js-is-it-possible-to-line-transition-by-key-instead-of-index)) but I wasn't sure, as the circumstances were different. Sorry if this is a repeat

Comment: When you're working with D3, there's almost never a need to use loops. What you're doing is a case for [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) (instead of the `.forEach()` loop). This will also fix the problem you're having at the moment -- you're giving all the elements the same ID (something which you should never do to start with) and selecting and manipulating all the lines in each iteration of your update loop.

Comment: Tho to be honest I'm not totally sure I understand how to apply it to the above.

Comment: In your case you don't even need a nested selection actually -- it would be simply `graph.selectAll("path").data(dataNest).enter().append("path").attr("d", function(d) { return line1(d.values); })` initially and then `graph.selectAll("path").transition().attr("d", function(d) { return line2(d.values); })`.